# Getting error when truing to save value from input to localStorage

Tags: javascript

Getting error when truing to save value from input to localStorage

> res.html is not a function

Here is my code:

```
Enter Text: <input type="text" id="inp" onchange="myFunction()">
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var res = document.getElementById('result');

function myFunction() {

var str = res.innerHTML = inp.value;

localStorage.setItem('value', str); 

if(localStorage.getItem('value')) {
    res.html(localStorage.getItem('value'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` is a JQuery function not a JavaScript one. To achieve what you're doing using JavaScript, you would use `.innerHTML`. So for example:

```
res.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to use [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) instead of [`html()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp). That's a jQuery function.

```
res.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not localStorage issue. html is not a defined function in DOM

You can do:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('value')) {
    res.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('value');
}
```